# Are there any good F# text editors?

Tags: f#, text-editor

Are there any good **text editors** for F#?

Instead of firing up resource-intensive Visual Studio, I would like to know if there are any text editors that can pretty-format F# code.

I am just getting started with F# and learning through FSI.exe with Notepad is giving me so much trouble...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check this out:
[F# Without Visual Studio](http://plus.kaist.ac.kr/~shoh/fsharp/html/fsharp-without-visual-studio.html)

Comment: Hmm. I haven't touched X/Emacs for like 5 years...  Maybe I can check out VIM...(never tried it)

Answer (score 9):

Not to be too much of a tease, but looking ahead, VS2010 uses a new rehostable editor component, you can hear some about it here: [Hanselminutes Podcast 147 - The new WPF-based Text Editor in Visual Studio 2010 - Interview with a Dev](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast147TheNewWPFbasedTextEditorInVisualStudio2010InterviewWithADev.aspx)

Anyway, this means that the F# editing experience in VS can, in theory, be completely decoupled from VS and hosted in a lightweight editor.  Which means it's possible F# could ship a sample or something that's 'the VS editing experience' (tooltips, squiggles, intellisense, ...) without VS.

To be clear, we on the F# team don't yet have any concrete plans to ship such a thing, but the new internal factoring of VS and the editor and MEF and whatnot should make this easy to do (we've prototyped it over a weekend, and it mostly works).  So hopefully look forward to cool things in the future.

Comment: I think having the VS2010 CTP expire on 1 Jan was enough of a tease :P

Comment: I will be looking forward to it.  But in the meantime, I will try out VIM.

Answer (score 5):

Two other options:

1. SharpDevelop with F# plugin from Robert Pickering.
2. Visual Studio 2008 Shell with F# CTP

Answer (score 3):

Any editor which will handle OCaml should handle F# -okay-. Mostly you just needs tabs. I'd recommend KomodoEdit, personally.

Comment: @Anthony, do you know what template I should start with? I don't see either F# or OCaml...  I am not sure what other languages is a derivative of OCaml.

Comment: I actually just meant for having nice tabbing support. If you just start as a blank file, and then choose "View As Language", Erlang will provide some syntax highlighting on some keywords. Not a perfect solution - just a suggestion. (I'm using Komodo, not Kom.Edit, so I'm only assuming the View As Lang. feature is shared.)

Comment: Would it handle F# layout (i.e. indentation) driven syntax okay?

Answer (score 3):

For notepad ++ someone made a file and put it up on the wiki:

http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/userDefineLang_Fsharp.xml

Answer (score 0):

One other option:

1. xacc.ide, a small ide that supports a bunch of .NET languages. But frankly, I haven't use it for a while since I'm really happy with Visual Studio 2008 (IntelliSense, interactive syntax checking, fsi, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You can setup [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) to work with F# as described here http://blog.kulman.sk/using-sublime-text-2-as-f-repl/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ionide](http://ionide.io/) package to integrate with [Visual Studio Code (VS Code)](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Atom](https://atom.io/) editors.

Here is an article "[F# Support in Visual Studio Code with Ionide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/03/guest-post-announcing-f-support-in-visual-studio-code-with-ionide/)"