# F# Editor for Linux

Tags: linux, f#

I am about to develop a F# project in Linux, but I don't know of any good editors with F# support.

Google is no real help either, since the results tend to be [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762502/are-there-any-good-f-text-editors) [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210125/is-there-any-f-ide-that-works-over-mono) (FunctionalVariations plugin for MonoDevelop anyone?).

What text editors with F# syntax highlighting and IntelliSense support are there for Linux? What do you guys use?

Comment: Vim works quite well

Comment: @JohnPalmer, thanks, I'll check it out. But at first glance it looks like it has the steepest of learning curves ;)

Comment: (@NikontheThird I think you'll find vim to have a [*gentle* learning curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve#.22Steep_learning_curve.22).)

Comment: The fsharp mode for Emacs is cool https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/blob/master/emacs/README.md (speaking of learning curves :-)), but Xamarin Studio has most Visual Studio features (+some more) and has fantastic F# support.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I really appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: Just go with MonoDevelop - it's almost where VS + ReSharper is and has quite nice F# support - but you probably have to compile it yourself (if you are at it grab the F# compiler fresh as well)

Comment: [Ionide](http://ionide.io/) works in [Atom](https://atom.io/) and [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs)

Comment: You can write F# in Visual Studio Code with the Ionide plugin. http://ionide.io/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

- [Monodevelop ide](http://monodevelop.com/) with F# addin, see [info](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/blob/master/monodevelop/). Stable and lot of features.
- emacs with F# mode, see [info](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/blob/master/emacs/)
- SublimeText 3, see [info](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/tree/master/sublimetext)
- others (SublimeText 2, vim) less complete, see [info](http://fsharp.org/guides/mac-linux-cross-platform/index.html#editing)
- F# plugin (alpha) for [Lighttable](http://www.lighttable.com/), see [info](https://github.com/enricosada/LightTable-FSharp)

The F# editor plugins (like monodevelop/xamarinstudio/emacs/sublimetext) sources are at repository https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding

All editor plugins are based on the common project [FSharp.Compiler.Service](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/)

A note:
You will often see F# tutorials on [XamarinStudio](http://xamarin.com/studio). XamarinStudio is based Monodevelop, and the F# plugin is the same. Xamarin sponsor the work of the plugin ( open source https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding ).